# Mann-Whitney-U test or unpaired-T test if only one group non-normal

Tags: r, normal-distribution, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

If I have two patient groups (disease+ vs disease-) and I want to compare both groups in terms of their BMI. There are n = 30 in the disease+ group while only n = 18 in the non-disease group. As far as I understand, the first step is to check the normality of the BMI data in each group and I used the following code:

```
with(mydata, shapiro.test(BMI[disease_status == "none"]))
with(mydata, shapiro.test(BMI[disease_status == "disease"]))
```

I want to ask if the disease group yields the p-value >0.05 after the Shapiro test while the non-disease group yields the p-value < 0.05, does it mean I should use the Mann-Whitney U test?

(I know if both p are < 0.05, then I must use the MW-U test but I am not sure what to do if only one p is < 0.05).

Comment: If the goal is to know whether BMI means differ between the two groups ('disease' and not), then use 2-sample t for nearly-normal data. If samples are not from normal population but of similar shapes, use 2-sample Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon rank sum test to see if medians differ. (M-W and Wilcoxon RS are equivalent but use different test statistics. Some stat software uses M-W, some Wilcoxon SR.)

Comment: The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitnney isn't a test of difference in medians either.

Comment: Indeed we've had several very confused people posting to ask why their Mann-Whitney rejects when the sample medians are identical; this is a confusion caused by this mistaken notion that it tests medians. On occasion you can even see it pick up an effect running in the opposite direction to the direction of difference in medians.

Answer (score 2):

Session using R:

(1) **Nearly normal data:** `x1` no disease, `x2` disease

```
summary(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  16.07   18.66   19.85   19.91   20.98   23.57 
summary(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  19.90   22.39   23.09   23.36   24.52   27.34
```

Shapiro-Wilk tests may not be accurate for small samples.
Also, these data are rounded to two places and, strictly
speaking, rounded normal data are not exactly normal.
Nevertheless, both samples are consistent with samples
from normal populations, according to Shapio-Wilk tests:

```
shapiro.test(x1)$p.val
[1] 0.7933927
shapiro.test(x2)$p.val
[1] 0.9602677
```

Many statisticians would prefer looking at normal Q-Q
plots to check for approximate normality. Plots should
be nearly linear (except possibly with some minor 'wobbles'
near the lower and upper tails). The plots below are
consistent with normal data.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 qqnorm(x1, main="Q-Q of 1st Sample")
  qqline(x1, col="blue")
 qqnorm(x2, main="Q-Q Plot of 2nd Sample")
  qqline(x2, col="blue")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

A Welch 2-sample t test finds a significant difference
between the two sample means. (A Welch test does not
require equal variances and so is preferable to a pooled
test unless we have advance knowledge that populations
have equal variances)

```
t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -7.3334, df = 56.567, p-value = 9.217e-10
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.393060 -2.508273
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 19.90600  23.35667
```

(2) **Right-skewed, non-normal data:** `y1` no disease, `y2` disease

```
summary(y1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   5.29   13.16   16.77   19.61   24.30   43.87 
 sd(y1)
 [1] 9.359215

summary(y2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   7.70   15.76   23.84   24.45   31.57   61.93 
sd(y2)
[1] 11.37608
```

Boxplots (`y1` bottom), show that both samples are moderately right-skewed with some boxplot outliers at the right. The 'notches' in
the sides of the boxes overlap, suggesting that we will
not find a significant difference in locations.

```
boxplot(y1,y2, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T,notch=T)
```

[image]

Neither sample passes the Shapiro-Wilk normality test; both
give P-values below 5%.

```
shapiro.test(y1)$p.val
[1] 0.04737606
shapiro.test(y2)$p.val
[1] 0.02658591
```

A 2-sample nonparametric Wilcoxon rank sum test does not find a significant difference in locations at the 5% level:

```
wilcox.test(y1, y2)

         Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  y1 and y2
W = 329, p-value = 0.0747
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

*Note:* You may find additional useful information
in some of the 'Related' links shown in the margin
of this page.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! You showed two examples (both passed vs both failed the Shapiro-Wilk normality). However, my original concern is if one pass but one fails...Do you know what to do next if that is the case?

Comment: If either of the two samples is clearly not normal, I would not use the t test.